# Keeping Listener.htm Running

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

```
<content src="index.htm" >
    <rim:background src="listener.htm" runOnStartup="true" />
</content>
```

I have a background listener and a foreground process called index.htm. When I install the app and load up the phone, I can see that my listener is in the background by holding down the menu button. However as soon as I load up the app itself and close it the listener is no longer in the background. What is the appropriate way to keep the listener ALWAYS running?

Do I have to use static void requestBackground() in the index.htm file somehow - Is that how the listener is activated? Also I require that the listener runs even when index.htm is in the foreground, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar issue. There are two distinct problems here:

- The background page closes and is replaced by the foreground page, when the app is made foreground.
- The app exits, closing the foreground page, when a user closes the app.

My solution to the first issue was to have the foreground and background pages be the same page i.e. index.html, and essentially have my app all in this one page.
To stop the application being terminated when you exit, I had to capture the [blackberry.app.event.onExit](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.event.html#.onExit) event and make it fire [blackberry.app.requestBackground()](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.html#.requestBackground) instead.